# Unity 2D two Circles collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am new to Unity and trying to write a 2D programm where I have multiple circles on a screen and make them change direction everytime they collide with another circle or a margin.

Here is the code I wrote for when a circle collides with a margin, in the Update method:

```
transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
if (transform.position.y < GameManager.bottomLeft.y + radius && direction.y < 0)
{
    direction.y = -direction.y;
}
if(transform.position.y > GameManager.topRight.y - radius && direction.y > 0)
{
    direction.y = -direction.y;
}
if(transform.position.x < GameManager.bottomLeft.x + radius && direction.x < 0)
{
    direction.x = -direction.x;
}
if(transform.position.x > GameManager.topRight.x - radius && direction.x > 0)
{
    direction.x = -direction.x;
}
```

direction is defined as `new Vector2(Random.value, Random.value)` in `Start` method. Now I read on the internet that if two circles meet, I can implement the behaviour in

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.tag == "Ball")
    {
    }  
}
```

How can I write the code so that two circles change directions when colliding?

Comment: multiply x and y by -1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you defined `direction` but this changes both objects `direction` upon a collision if the collider is tagged as `Ball`, however if you are trying to do something more like a mirrored movement you may want to change something with rotation.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.tag == "Ball")
    {
        GameObject CollidedObject = collision.gameObject;
        CollidedObject.direction.x = -CollidedObject.direction.x;
        CollidedObject.direction.y = -CollidedObject.direction.y;
        this.direction.x = -this.direction.x;
        this.direction.y = -this.direction.y;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Direction is defined as a new Vector2 with random x and y.  The problem is when I write the code so that only the direction of "this" gets -direction, it works, but it will change direction only for one of the objects and I want both of them to change. So when I write that code, it does not work

Comment: If the other object that collides with your object has a field called `direction` too, the code I've wrote should be able to work. Did you try it?